# Instance unknown to class

Tags: php, class, oop

I hope you can help me with a problem I just faced. I'm trying to get all my classes that are stored in a folder `/classes` known to every class. This is the way I tried: I created a class called Main, that stores an instance of every class of the /classes-folder:

```
<?php

// Include classes:
$dir = './classes/';
$dh = opendir($dir);
while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
    if (is_file($dir . $file) AND substr($file, 0, 2) == 'c_') {
        include_once($dir . $file);
    }
}

class Main {

    PUBLIC function __construct() {
        foreach ($GLOBALS['className'] as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$value} = new $value;
        }
    }

    PUBLIC function gI($classObject) { return $this->{$classObject}; }

}

$Main = new Main;

?>
```

Every other class I user extends the class Main like this:

```
include_once('./c_main.php');

class Kernel extends Main {

    public function hello() { 
        var_dump($this->gI('Session')); // /classes/c_session.php
    }

...
```

This is what `c_session.php` looks:

```
<?php

include_once('./c_main.php');

class Session extends Main {

    ...

}

$className[] = 'Session'; // so $GLOBALS['className'] stores every class
```

?>

I expected `var_dump($this->gI('Session`))`to return an instance of`class Session`but it's`Null`. Any ideas why? I you have any other ideas to get all classes globally known, I'm open for suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: So where is `$GLOBALS['className']` defined?

Comment: at the end of every "class-file", take a look at c_session.php

Comment: And why don't you simply use a normal spl autoloader?

Comment: This is what nightmares are born of. Use interfaces and traits. Extending classes can be usefull but should not be overused.

Comment: I dont know how, is it a simple and fast way for my problem?

Comment: I was just looking to fix my issues, if there is a better way I'm open for it!

Comment: Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for autoloading. You don't have to include external libraries for it to be usefull!

Comment: It's a lot easier and more efficient.... class files are only loaded if/when they're actually needed to start with.... also allows your classes to accept constructor arguments

Comment: okay, sounds good! I also got the  problem that my database class throws an error, that there are too many connections! i think this is an result of uselessly loading every class too much. how can i get into the spl autoloader?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-unregister.php and http://www.czettner.com/blog/13/11/01/spl-autoloader-tutorial-juniors might give you a start

Comment: thank you! that looks great, OIS suggested to use composer, do you have any experiences with this? are there any advantages in using the one or the other?

Comment: Okay I got autoloader working, but I have one last question. Now, that I can use every class in every class, how should I call it? E.g. I got to classes, `Class1` and `Class2`. Within the methods of Class2, how shall I call methods from Class1? `Class1::Method()`? This isn't quite OOP style, right? Whats a good way?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md):

Put all classes in *src* folder with namespace *MyNameSpace*, like this:

src/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace MyNameSpace;

class Test {}
```

composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "me/test",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyNameSpace\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Use the command "composer update" then **require_once "vendor/autoload.php";** in your PHP files which are not in src.

Example index.php:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$test = new MyNameSpace\Test;
```

Example external packages:

- [The League](https://thephpleague.com/)
- [github](https://github.com/trending?l=PHP&since=monthly)

Example installing external code from commandline:

*composer require league/url*

Comment: do I have to install anything to my server or just create the files?

Comment: You have to install composer either on the server to generate the autoload or on your dev machine and upload the vendor folder.

Comment: ah I see. So when I install it locally and use my ftp programm it'll work online as well? is composer better than the spl_autoload-functions?

Comment: Composer uses the spl_autoload functions for you. It also installs external libraries from github or your own version control server and sets up autoloading for them. This is a good step towards using external code instead of writing everything yourself. :)

Comment: ah okay! thank you! i always wanted to do everything myself but by know i got quite a huge cms coded myself which I'm trying to get faster right now. I thing composer and spl might help me! thanks guys!